# How can I iterate though grid cells as a 2d array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, grid, iteration, cell

[Original Grid view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FReoW.png)

I have ths grid created with

```js
for(let i = 0; i < 25; i++){
  var item = document.createElement("div");
  grid.append(item);
}
```

And grid in html/css created like this

```css
.grid {
   display: grid
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
</div>
```

I have a snake and all coordinates that are mentioned in format [number, number]
So the snake looks like
[GRID WITH SNAKE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYsiC.png)

```js
let snake = [
   [2,2],
   [3,2],
   [4,2]
]
```

How can I iterate through grid cells (divs that I created) to add class "snake" with background color green?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the position of the snake-part from it's row/column, and use [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) in a selector to target that box in the grid with [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Note: to be extra-cautious maybe check that `pos` doesn't exceed your grid bounds, and maybe log an error if it does.

```js
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');

const snake = [[2,2],[3,2],[4,2]];

// Create the grid adding classes to the boxes
// so they can intitially be seen
for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  const box = document.createElement('div');
  box.classList.add('box');
  grid.append(box);
}

// Using the row/column from the snake-part array
// calculate its position in the grid
function getPosition([ row, column ]) {
  return (row * 5) + (column + 1);
}

// For each snake-part array get the position,
// create a selector using `nth-child`,
// find that box in the grid, and add a new class to it
for (let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  const pos = getPosition(snake[i]);
  const selector = `.box:nth-child(${pos})`;
  const box = grid.querySelector(selector);
  box.classList.add('snake');  
}
```

```css
.grid { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 30px); gap: 2px; }
.box { width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: #efefef;}
.snake { background-color: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<div class="grid"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way,

```js
const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");

for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  var item = document.createElement("div");

  // save grid coordinates in the div element
  // e.g. <div data-x="0" data-y="0"></div>

  // get x coords 24 / 5 => Math.floor(4.8) => 4
  const x = Math.floor(i / 5);
  // get y coords e.g. 24 % 5 = 4
  const y = i % 5;

  item.dataset.x = x;
  item.dataset.y = y;

  // this is just to display coordinates.
  item.textContent = `(${x}, ${y})`; 
  // 

  grid.append(item);
}

// snake coords [x, y]

let snake = [
  [2, 2],
  [3, 2],
  [4, 2]
];

// [x, y] - this is array destructing is action.
for (let [x, y] of snake) {
  // find the corosponding div element.
  const item = grid.querySelector(`[data-x="${x}"][data-y="${y}"]`);
  item.style.background = "green";
}
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 40px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 40px);
}

.grid > div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a strategy to quickly access the grid elements in the indices required. You can use the grid's querySelector but for a more general approach, you can assign an `id/class` to the `div` elements and use it in JS to access the block.

```
// for 5x5 matrix
for(let i = 0; i < 25; i++){
  const row = parseInt(i/5);
  const col = i%5;
  var item = document.createElement("div");
  item.setAttribute("id", row+"_"+col);
  grid.append(item);
}
```

This should give you something like this

[image]

Now, you can use your snake coordinates, say [3,4], the div id will be `3_4`, so you can simply do

```
const snake_element = document.getElementById(snake_coordinate[0]+"_"+snake_coordinate[1])
// apply your styles here
```

Also, if you are unable to use ids for some reason, you can add a CSS class in the same way

```
// in the loop
...
item.className=row+"_"+col;
grid.append(item);
...

// to access the element
const snake_element = document.getElementsByClassName(snake_coordinate[0]+"_"+snake_coordinate[1])[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you trying to draw in 2d space.
1-dimensional array isn't a good solution for such task. It's better to use a 2d matrix to store your divs.

```
const grid = [];

// Assume it's 5x5 field
const xLength = 5
const yLength = 5;

for(let i = 0; i < xLength; i++){
    grid.push([]);

    for(let j = 0; j < yLength; j++){
        const item = document.createElement("div");
        grid[i].push(item);
    }
}
```

So now you can easily access each element by index.

```
const snake = [
    [2, 2],
    [3, 2],
    [4, 2]
];

snake.forEach(([x, y]) => {
    grid[x][y].classList.add("my-class");
});
```

But it'll work only if your grid has fixed dimensions.